# Why would I ever want to explicitly include a PartitionKey when upserting an item with CosmosClient?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

`UpsertItemAsync` has an optional parameter where you can indicate the `PartitionKey`.

This is for the 'new' CosmosClient and not for the 'old' DocumentClient.

[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.upsertitemasync?view=azure-dotnet

As the documentation says - it is optional because if you do not supply one, it will be automatically extracted from the item. Isn't that perfect?

Is there any conceivable situation under any circumstances where that is not what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because extracting the PartitionKey means that the SDK needs to parse the item and figure out which is the correct attribute and all that takes computational time. Reference https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Resource/Container/ContainerCore.Items.cs#L506

If you know ahead of time which is the PartitionKey value, it will improve the overall performance of the operation.

Comment: Thanks. That code to extract the PartitionKey is more complex than I had imagined. Still must be a very small overhead.

Comment: In a single operation it is probably small overhead, but if you are doing a big amount of concurrent operations, then that small overhead starts to add up.