# Why does Container.CreateItemAsync have a partitionKey parameter?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

With regards to the `partitionKey` parameter, the [docs for Container.CreateItemAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.createitemasync) says:

> PartitionKey for the item. If not specified will be populated by extracting from {T}

It is true, when left as `null` the API works and uses the partition key in the provided document model. However, the reverse does not work -- if I do not provide a partition key in the model (no property at all so that a field is not even serialized), but I provide the parameter, I get this error:

> PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified in the header

So there is never a case where I am not required to provide the partition key in the model, but I can optionally provide it as a parameter.

Then why have the parameter at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would I ever want to explicitly include a PartitionKey when upserting an item with CosmosClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58216945/why-would-i-ever-want-to-explicitly-include-a-partitionkey-when-upserting-an-ite)

Answer (score 0):

It maybe helpful if you're going through the source code.

When it calls [public abstract Task<ItemResponse> CreateItemAsync()](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/8b174b2e6f49ddbda1abbfe24b8a3a5247e0e267/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Resource/Container/Container.cs#L375) method, the implemented method [public async Task<ItemResponse> CreateItemAsync()](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/3172a1af13b3738a79c2eb8db234e84a76d5cf1d/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Resource/Container/ContainerCore.Items.cs#L66) is actually executed.

Inside that method, you can see it uses [private async Task ExtractPartitionKeyAndProcessItemStreamAsync()](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/3172a1af13b3738a79c2eb8db234e84a76d5cf1d/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Resource/Container/ContainerCore.Items.cs#L748) method to process `partitionKey` like below:

1. If user specifies a partitionKey, it will check the value is valid or not, then decide to use the partitionKey or not. The code is [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/3172a1af13b3738a79c2eb8db234e84a76d5cf1d/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Resource/Container/ContainerCore.Items.cs#L770).
2. If user does not specify a partitionkey, this code will be executed to automatically fetch it from model. The code is [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/3172a1af13b3738a79c2eb8db234e84a76d5cf1d/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Resource/Container/ContainerCore.Items.cs#L790).

So in short, the answer is that the parameter here is for someone who wants to specify a custom partitionKey(but should be valid, the source code will check it), and does not want to automatically extract partitionKey from model.

Comment: But at the service layer, which we don't have source code for, they do extract it also and the evidence of that is the error message. So maybe I should rephrase the question to not ask about the .NET API, but the service API itself. If I had to guess what is going on, Cosmos receives this request and if it has the header it can send the create request to the specific physical partition to do the create. Without the header the Cosmos front door fans the request to all physical partitions which proceed to deserialize the model and ignore the create request if does not apply. Just a guess...

Comment: @Agendum Your guess maybe correct. But anyway when you call the `createitemasync` method, in the server side, the source code will do the thing.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58216945) is very similar to mine and the answer there is that it is to benefit performance (so that the client code doesn't have to parse out using the code you outlined). The reason I am uncomfortable with the answer is the service is doing it anyway, regardless if the client code provides it in a header. If the service code parses it regardless, then why require it in the header?